# Heroku Application Error: understanding the logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I just pushed my rails app to Heroku. Then I ran heroku db:migrate then heroku db:push. But when I open the app I get the error "An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details".

So I ran heroku logs and this is what I get:

```
$ heroku logs
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460654+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.461171+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.461171+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.461171+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460325+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': /app/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:54: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460325+00:00 app[web.1]:         redirect_to signin_url, notice: t "user.please"
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460325+00:00 app[web.1]:         ^
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460325+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460325+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460654+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460654+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460654+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.461171+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.461171+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.461171+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.461171+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.461171+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460325+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460325+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460654+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460654+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460325+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_
or_load'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460896+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460896+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460896+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'

2013-05-10T17:13:21.461171+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.461416+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'

2013-05-10T17:13:21.460896+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460896+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.461171+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460896+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:
5:in `<top (required)>'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460896+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `requir
e'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460896+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block
in <main>'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460896+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460896+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460325+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'

2013-05-10T17:13:21.461416+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2013-05-10T17:13:23.235761+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-05-10T17:13:23.221686+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-05-10T17:13:23.237632+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-05-10T17:13:24.507187+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
undle exec rails server -p 10305`
2013-05-10T17:13:27.937367+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails
 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed
in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to
your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release
notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-h
as-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)

2013-05-10T17:13:27.935835+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails
 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed
in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to
your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release
notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-h
as-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)

2013-05-10T17:13:27.938348+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails
 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed
in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to
your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release
notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-h
as-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)

2013-05-10T17:13:31.274313+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-05-10T17:13:31.274313+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-05-10T17:13:31.274313+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-05-10T17:13:31.274313+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.12 application startin
g in production on http://0.0.0.0:10305
2013-05-10T17:13:31.274313+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by
 DATABASE_URL
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512180+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <modul
e:Finisher>'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.511810+00:00 app[web.1]:         redirect_to signin_url, not
ice: t "user.please"
2013-05-10T17:13:31.511810+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'

2013-05-10T17:13:31.511810+00:00 app[web.1]:
        ^
2013-05-10T17:13:31.511810+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-05-10T17:13:31.511810+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_
or_load'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512180+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engin
e.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.511810+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': /app/a
pp/controllers/users_controller.rb:54: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, exp
ecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512434+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'

2013-05-10T17:13:31.512434+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512434+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `requir
e'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512702+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512180+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.511810+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dep
endency'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.511810+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in
 require'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.511810+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_
dependency'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512180+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512180+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializ
ers'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512434+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512702+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512434+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:
5:in `<top (required)>'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.511810+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_o
n'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512702+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512434+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512702+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512702+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512991+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512180+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512180+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512180+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512434+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512434+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512991+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'

2013-05-10T17:13:31.512702+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512702+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512180+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512434+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block
in <main>'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512702+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512702+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512180+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512434+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-05-10T17:13:31.512702+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2013-05-10T17:13:42.307007+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-05-10T17:13:42.323377+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-05-10T17:13:55.228036+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bun
dle exec rake db:migrate` by muyiwamat@gmail.com
2013-05-10T17:13:57.306953+00:00 heroku[run.6043]: Awaiting client
2013-05-10T17:13:57.324094+00:00 heroku[run.6043]: Starting process with command
 `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-05-10T17:13:58.232657+00:00 heroku[run.6043]: State changed from starting t
o up
2013-05-10T17:14:06.400819+00:00 heroku[run.6043]: Process exited with status 0
2013-05-10T17:14:06.419565+00:00 heroku[run.6043]: State changed from up to comp
lete
2013-05-10T17:17:30.518444+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/ host=immense-refuge-9281.herokuapp.com fwd="94.116.4.100
" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-05-10T17:17:30.975159+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=immense-refuge-9281.herokuapp.com fwd="9
4.116.4.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I can barely make any sense of this files up here. Is there anything I might be doing wrong? I'm using Rails 3.2 and I already made sure I used heroku --stack cedar because I read somewhere that heroku only supports Rails 3 on the cedar stack.

--UPDATE--
As requested by Leo Correa below is a snippet of my users_controller.rb

```
def signed_in_user
     unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to (signin_url, notice: t("user.please")) 
     end
    end
```

Comment: +1 Did you resolve this problem? If so, what was the fix? I'm having a different problem with Heroku but I have not gotten any help on SO as yet.

Answer (score 3):

That seems like a syntax error and you might be missing something like a curly brace or parenthesis

```
/app/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:54: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)
2013-05-10T17:13:21.460325+00:00 app[web.1]:         redirect_to signin_url, notice: t "user.please"
```

That chunk gives it away. So somewhere in your users_controller on line 54. Try doing this

```
redirect_to(signing_url, notice: t('user.please'))
```

Comment: Did you make sure you commit the changes then pushed? Can you post the snippet of your `users_controller.rb` at line 54?

Comment: Yes i committed the changes. I've added the snippet

Answer (score 1):

I think it's problem of assets pre compiling you need to add `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` in `config/application.rb`. If it is added in `config/environments/production.rb`

From your log it seems syntax error like:

```
redirect_to(signing_url, notice: t('user.please'))
```

I think you are using `Devise Gem` Check your code.

Comment: No I'm not using the devise gem. The authentication was son from scratch. Also, there is no such line as `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` in my production.rb should I still add it to application.rb anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You might using free account of heroku. When you are using free account of heroku you can use only 18 hours a day and then automatically goes to sleep state or gets exhausted. When it happens you will get this error page. Try to skip the account to hobby type if your site busy.

Comment: Heroku started to reduce usage time of free dynos to 18 hours a day in 2015. The question is from 2013 so I don't think that was the problem.

Comment: Yeah thats right Dani.. Actually I posted this for current users of heroku.. coz I myself faced the problem when it got exhausted. In somecase it might be useful to someone.